# Why I can't access array after loop?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Working with Google Maps API and AngularJS (1.5.8). After creating markers in loop, I can't access them after. This code inside initMap function:

```
var markers = [];

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){

    var html = $scope.posts[i].address;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: {lat: parseFloat($scope.posts[i].lat), lng: parseFloat($scope.posts[i].lng)}
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    bindInfoWindow(markers[i], map, infoWindow, html);

}

markers // no error messages, nothing
console.log(markers); // still nothing
```

EDIT:

The error was in

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
```

Changed to:

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.posts.length; i++)
```

Thanks to @Maxx and thanks to all who tried to help .
That was a silly mistake.

Comment: What's up with this: "markers // no error messages, nothing"? Does marker return something before you push it to markers? And what bindInfoWindow method does?

Comment: Please post your angular code as well. Or any other detail because it doesn't seem a clear question

Comment: @Ionut, I mean, there is no reaction at markers variable. I thought that browser's console will show error or something else. But nothing.

Comment: @49volro, why would you want to use it like that? It makes no sense.

Comment: @Ionut, for markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, options)

Comment: `console.log(markers); // still nothing` has to output **something** even if it is `[]` to indicate an empty array or `undefined` to show that your array has been overwritten with the undefined value. If nothing is being output, then the most likely explanation is that the function isn't being called in the first place.

Comment: @49volro, again, when you do a console.log(marker) in your for loop, what do you get? Do you have any result?

Comment: @Ionut, only "Error: $scope.posts[i] is undefined", but.. I thought - OK, but it's working (markers are showing on map), think about that error later.

Comment: try to replace `i<10` with `i<$scope.posts.length`

Comment: @Maxx, Wow! Magic, but it's works!

Comment: @49volro thats not magic, you trying to access posts that doesn't exists in array

Comment: @Maxx, yeah, thanks! I just, I can't understand how I skipped that.

Answer (score 3):

> Error: $scope.posts[i] is undefined"

The script is throwing an exception on the line `var html = $scope.posts[i].address;`. It stops running at that point. Consequently, it **never reaches** `console.log(markers);`

> but.. I thought - OK, but it's working (markers are showing on map)

You're in a loop. Some of the markers are showing, then one of the values is undefined (not the first value!), so you get an exception and the script stops.

You can probably resolve this by looping up to the `length` of the array instead of a hard coded `10` items.

> , think about that error later.

Always deal with the first error first. They are often the causes of subsequent errors.